# Riyadh airport transit

Tags: transit, saudi-airlines, riyadh

I’m travelling from Budapest to Delhi on February, and I have a 2-hour transit in Riyadh. My Wizz Air flight is in terminal 1 and my flynas flight is in terminal 3.
I’ve got a multiple-entry e-visa and I’m only taking a small carry-on bag. Would that be enough time or should I change the dates?

Answer (score 4):

Given that this is a self-transfer, this means that:

- You need to deplane
- Make your way to passport control, queue, and get through
- Walk from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3
- If you weren't able to check-in online/on mobile, go to departures and check-in at the latest 60 minutes before departure
- Go through security
- Walk to your gate and get there at the latest 15 minutes before departure.

**If all goes well (no delays), if you can check-in online or on mobile, as you already have a visa and don't have hold luggage** to collect and check back in, this should be doable.

However, if your incoming flight is late and you miss your connection, remember that the second airline will simply consider you a no-show and cancel your ticket (with no refund). You then have to find, book and pay for a new flight, at last minute prices, and if relevant, find and pay for a hotel, etc.

The usual recommendation for self-transfers is to have at least 4 hours between flights, possibly (a lot) more depending on the circumstances. While this not guarantee you won't miss your second flight, it reduces the risk quite a bit.

Also remember that it happens quite often that airlines change their schedules between the time you book your flight and the actual flight. If the that happens and the new schedules are no longer compatible, you will usually have to book and pay for a new flight or pay change fees and fare difference, depending on the flexibility of your tickets.